# Ajax, не добавляется первая запись в html

Tags: javascript, ajax, html5

Добрый день, подскажите.
Есть запрос ajax, он работает, данные в БД передаются, ответ приходит, если в БД есть хоть 1 запись, то полученные данные добавляются на страницу html. Если запись первая, то блок html обновляется, но записи нет, если нажать ф5 запись появляется и только после этого js нормально добавляет остальные записи.

```js
$(doc).ready(function() {
  //Обращаемся к форме по ID
  $('#addFormPedigree').submit(function(event) {
    //Отключаем форму
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: $(this).attr('method'),
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      data: new FormData(this),
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(result) {

        $(".PedigreeForm").children().html("");

        for (var el, i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          el = result[i];

          $("#Pedigree" + el.breed).append("<div class='d-flex flex-row mb-2 align-items-center justify-content-between FilterItemSub2Title delBlock" + el.id + "'><span>" + el.name_pedigree + "</span><span class='mr-2'><i class='fas fa-pencil-alt iconColorBlue'></i> | <a title='Удалить' class='delBreedIds btnCursor' id='" + el.id + "'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt iconColorRed'></i></a></span></div>");
        }
        $('#myModalPedigree').modal('hide');
        $('#myModalSuccess').modal('show');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="collapse mt-2 PedigreeForm" id="collapsePedigree<?echo $breeds['id']?>">
  <?foreach ($pedigree as $p): ?>
    <?if($p['breed'] == $breeds['id']):?>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column" id="PedigreeForm<?echo $breeds['id']?>">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row mb-2 align-items-center justify-content-between FilterItemSub2Title delBlock<?echo $p['id'];?>">
          <span><?echo $p['name_pedigree'];?></span>
          <span class="mr-2"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt iconColorBlue"></i> | <a title="Удалить" class="delBreedIds btnCursor" id="<?echo $p['id'];?>"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt iconColorRed"></i></a></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column" id="Pedigree<?echo $breeds['id']?>"></div>
      <?endif;?>
        <?endforeach;?>
</div>
<?endforeach;?>
```

Comment: В одно строке вы обращаетесь к форме `$('#addFormPedigree')`, а в другой  `$(".PedigreeForm")` - это норм?

Comment: addFormPedigree - это форма, которая находится под футером.